# SGEN (x86): Tells me .NET4.6 is required

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2015, sgen

I've installed Visual Studio 2015 and am trying to upgrade our (32bit) VS2010 projects.
When the project compiles, it tries to run SGEN (Generate Serialization Assembly=on) from

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v10.0A\bin\NETFX 4.6 Tools\sgen.exe
```

Either from the command line, or in visual studio, this window appears and no command line options presented for sgen:

[image]

This is .NET 4.6 installed as part of VS2015 (release). I can run 32bit .Net 4.6 assemblies, so it has been installed.

Using 'repair' on the .Net4.6 installation did not fix the problem or report any problems. The registry keys for .NET x86 and x64 appear to be sound (and the same version).

Logged in [Microsoft Connect](https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/1601402/running-sgen-exe-prompts-for-net-4-6)

Comment: The second error is obvious - you can't use a x64 tool on a x86 dll

Comment: Yep I know, it was a desperate hope that they'd shimmed the 32bit logic in the x64 tool.

Comment: What do you get if you simply run sgen? What is the version number? On my machine it's 4.6.81. You may have to repair your installation

Comment: C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v10.0A\bin\NETFX 4.6 Tools\sgen.exe has no version number, running it produces a modal dialog box telling me to install .Net 4.6. However I can run gacutil, regasm

Comment: Updated the post with the picture I get when I type in sgen.exe

Comment: Then you probably have a broken installation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out it was entirely our fault.

As part of our upgrade, our build environment notes told us to add  a .config file to sgen which we adapted for .net 4.6:

```
<configuration>
<runtime>
    <loadFromRemoteSources enabled="true" />
</runtime>
<startup useLegacyV2RuntimeActivationPolicy="true">
    <supportedRuntime version="v4.6"/>
</startup>
</configuration>
```

Removing this explicit supportedRuntime tag fixed the issue.

Answer (score -1):

A workaround is to point your build target step at

C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v8.1A\bin\NETFX 4.5.1 Tools